# D3.js - Date string comparion fails ( minimum and maximum dates are not found)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to compare a set of date strings to get the maximum and minimum of it.
The following is the data set I have.

```
  var data=[{ "date": "2016.07.28", "close": 186889.45 }, { "date": 
 "2016.07.29", "close": 187156.54 }, { "date": "2016.08.01", "close": 
 187218.54 }, { "date": "2016.08.02", "close": 187624.73 }];
```

And, this is how I compare them.

```
         var parseTime = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse;

           max_x = 0, max_y = 0, min = 100;


           for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               max_y = Math.max(max_y, data[i].close);
               max_x = Math.max(max_x, parseTime (data[i].date));
               min = Math.min(min, parseTime (data[i].date));
           }
```

The date comparison does not seem to happen. 
Isn't this the way to compare date strings in javascript ?

I use d3 version 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
min = Math.min(min, parseTime (data[i].date));
max_x = Math.max(max_x, parseTime(data[i].date));
```

You are using `Math.max` and `Math.min` to compare a **date** with a **number**, and because of that you'll get the date in timestamp.

Look at the output of your code:

```js
var data = [{
  "date": "2016.07.28",
  "close": 186889.45
}, {
  "date": "2016.07.29",
  "close": 187156.54
}, {
  "date": "2016.08.01",
  "close": 187218.54
}, {
  "date": "2016.08.02",
  "close": 187624.73
}];

var parseTime = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse;

max_x = 0, max_y = 0, min = 100;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  max_y = Math.max(max_y, data[i].close);
  max_x = Math.max(max_x, parseTime(data[i].date));
  min = Math.min(min, parseTime(data[i].date));
}

console.log("Max is " + max_x)
console.log("Min is " + min)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

According to the ECMA [Documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.min), `Math.max` and `Math.min`:

> Given zero or more arguments, calls ToNumber on each of the arguments and returns the smallest of the resulting values.
>
> - If no arguments are given, the result is +∞.
> - If any value is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - The comparison of values to determine the smallest value is done using
>     the Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm (7.2.11) except that +0
>     is considered to be larger than −0.

Solution:

Use `d3.min` and `d3.max` instead.

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
  "date": "2016.07.28",
  "close": 186889.45
}, {
  "date": "2016.07.29",
  "close": 187156.54
}, {
  "date": "2016.08.01",
  "close": 187218.54
}, {
  "date": "2016.08.02",
  "close": 187624.73
}];

var parseTime = d3.time.format("%Y.%m.%d").parse;

var max = d3.max(data, function(d){ return parseTime(d.date)})
var min = d3.min(data, function(d){ return parseTime(d.date)})

console.log("Max is: " + max)
console.log("Min is: " + min)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You !   var extent = d3.extent(data.map(function (d) { return parseTime(d.date) }))

               max_x =extent[1];
               min = extent[0]; I used this, but the output format is not how I want it to be. I want it like ' 2016.07.16'. Any solution ?

Comment: Use `d3.time.format` to format your date object: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md

Comment: I've already used it. If you see my code above. still it doesn't work